# "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined." with ColdFusion and jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I am working on a ColdFusion page that creates a jQuery DataTable which should fetch JSON data.

For this I have initialized the DataTable in jQuery and given the proper URL for fetching the data, but in spite of this I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

#### 1. allCLient.cfm (returns JSON data)

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["CID", "NAME", "EMAIL", "CONTACT", "DOB", "GENDER", "QUALIFICATION", "DESIGNATION", "CITY", "DISTRICT", "MSTATUS", "PHOTO"],
    "DATA": [
        [39, "ramesh", "ramesh@gmail.com", 9494949491, "October, 07 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "MBA", "Tester", "delhi", "mumbai", "unmarried", null],
        [47, "neeraj", "neeraj@gmail.com", 9369369369, "June, 22 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "BE", "Tester", "UP", "UP", "married", null],
        [51, "deepak", "deepak@gmail.com", 8877556699, "August, 19 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "MCA", "Developer", "bhilai", "bhilai", "unmarried", null],
        [59, "vishwa", "vishwa@gmail.com", 8787878787, "October, 08 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "BCA", "Engineer", "durg", "mumbai", "unmarried", null],
        [60, "vivek", "vivek@gmail.com", 8965896589, "August, 17 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "BE", "Engineer", "jagdalpur", "jagdalpur", "married", null],
        [61, "tapas", "tapas@gmail.com", 8082858881, "November, 04 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "MCA", "Tester", "bilaspur", "bilaspur", "unmarried", null],
        [78, "vasu", "vas54@gmail.com", 8877887788, "June, 09 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "MCA", "Engineer", "bhilai", "durg", "unmarried", "ColdFusionTutorial.jpg"],
        [84, "devesh", "devesh@gmail.com", 9494949494, "February, 09 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "MCA", "Developer", "raipur", "raipur", "unmarried", "ColdFusionTutorial.jpg"],
        [88, "deepesh", "deepesh@gmail.com", 8978897889, "September, 14 2017 00:00:00", "Male", "BE", "Developer", "bhilai", "durg", "unmarried", "ColdFusionTutorial.jpg"]
    ]
}
```

#### 2. Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').DataTable({        
         "ajax": "allClient.cfm",
         "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "contact" },
            { "data": "designation" },
            { "data": "city" }            
        ]
    });
});
```

#### 3.  HTML

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

#### 4.   CFML code

```
  <cfquery datasource="cfprogrammer" name="getClient" result="cust">
        select * from client </cfquery>

 <cfif cust.recordcount gt 0>   


 <cfset myArr = ArrayNew(1)>

 <cfloop query = "getClient">
    <cfset mystrct = StructNew()>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct,'name',getClient.name)>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct,'email',getClient.email)>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct,'contact',getClient.contact)>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct,'designation',getClient.designation)>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct,'city',getClient.city)>

     <cfset ArrayAppend(myArr, mystrct)>
 </cfloop>

   <!--- <cfdump var="#myArr#">--->
   <cfset mystrct1 = StructNew()>
    <cfset StructInsert(mystrct1,'data',myArr)>
   <cfset myJSONvar = serializeJSON(mystrct1)>
   <cfoutput>#myJSONvar#</cfoutput>

<cfelse>
      Failed            
</cfif>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. If the JSON fields being returned are upper case then you need to use uppercase on the data table  {data: "EMAIL"}. Data tables also might not read it in that format. It Would just expect an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

When ColdFusion converts a query object to JSON, the result is structured like this by default:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["COLNAME-1", "COLNAME-2", "COLNAME-N"],
    "DATA": [
        ["row-1-data-1", "row-1-data-2", "row-1-data-N"],
        ["row-2-data-1", "row-2-data-2", "row-2-data-N"],
        ["row-3-data-1", "row-3-data-2", "row-3-data-N"]
    ]
}
```

but jQuery DataTable expects this format, a simple array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "COLNAME-1": "row-1-data-1", 
        "COLNAME-2": "row-1-data-2", 
        "COLNAME-N": "row-1-data-N"
    },
    {
        "COLNAME-1": "row-2-data-1", 
        "COLNAME-2": "row-2-data-2", 
        "COLNAME-N": "row-2-data-N"
    },
    {
        "COLNAME-1": "row-3-data-1", 
        "COLNAME-2": "row-3-data-2", 
        "COLNAME-N": "row-3-data-N"
    }
]
```

ColdFusion can create the second format with a special parameter to the [`SerializeJSON()` function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) (this parameter has been added in CF 2016, update 2):

```
<cfset jsonData = SerializeJSON(yourQuery, "struct")>
```

Now it depends on how your `allCLient.cfm` looks like. I suspect you simply call `SerializeJSON()` and output the result. In that case the above is enough.

Don't forget to set `<cfcontent type="application/json">`.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you need to be aware that ColdFusion is not case-sensitive and defaults to upper-case column names. Therefore your JSON will have upper-case keys as well. Javascript is case-sensitive which means you *must* use the upper-case form there.

Comment: when i gave second parameter which is "struct", then found 'parameter validation error', and in this case if i directly call the file "allClient.cfm" got error - 'The value of parameter 2, which is currently struct, must be a boolean value.'

Comment: and if i use serializeJSON with single parameter i.e. query name, i got the format which already mentioned above but jquery does not accept the same format.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using? The documentation clearly states the version constraints for the second parameter to `SerializeJSON()`. If you are stuck with an older version of CF, your best bet is to write a small JS function that transforms the first format into the second on the client side, after the Ajax request has been received and before you pass it on to the DataTable. jQuery DataTable supports [a `dataSrc` function to manipulate incoming JSON](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc), so that's not difficult to do.

Comment: Actually i am using coldfusion 10, and now the issue has been resolved by using struct and array for formatting the correct json format.

Comment: That's one way to do it, and it certainly solves this specific situation. But it is not portable. In the next query you want to send to the client you will face the same situation, so you will copy and paste the code, modify it for a different list of columns, etc. This is not elegant and it does not scale.

Comment: Its much better to find a way that can convert *any* data in format 1 to format 2. The best place to do this is the client side, because `SerializeJSON()` in CF gives you a string and it makes no sense to manipulate that string on the server side. But on the client side it's easy, because there it will be parsed into an array of objects automatically, and all you need to do is reorder it a bit. Write a `function convertFromCfQuery(data) { ... }` in JS that takes format 1 and returns format 2. You can then re-use this function in JS and keep your server-side code clean and simple.

Comment: That being said, on Stack Overflow it's not good to write the solution to your question *in* your question. Write the solution to your question as an answer.

Comment: ok thanks @Tomalak for the suggestions, i will also try to make it at client side.

Comment: In fact it will be a nested loop - the outer one over `"DATA"` for constructing objects, and the inner one over `"COLUMNS"`, filling those objects with properties. Very simple. I did that in 5 lines of JS code.

Comment: No, certainly not. I've already described what the code needs to do in English, that should be more than enough for you to write it down.Take it as a small challenge, it really isn't complicated.